# Two Way SSL with openssl/java

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, jks

I have a client application by java that want connect to server as Two Way SSL.
I create a pair keys as public/private. Public key name is **key.cert** and private key name is **key.pem**.
Then server side give to me a public key with **server.cert** name.
My questions are:

1. What convert three key(**key.cert\key.pem\server.cert**) in me side(client side) into a java **Key Store(JKS)**?
2. What create a **Socket** in code for connect to server?

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: Java Keystores (of any type) can easily be edited using the GUI Open Source Tool "Portecle". Anyway please improve the quality of your question.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you mean by *Two Way SSL*. SSL connection are bidirectional by their very nature. Or is your question rather about mutual *authentication*, typically achieved using SSL/TLS with client certificates?

Comment: @EJP sorry, I edited original question.

Comment: @f_puras Yes, meaning is mutual authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        System.out.println("Connecting to " +IP + "port "
                + Port);

        // load client private key
            KeyStore clientKeys = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            clientKeys.load(
                    new FileInputStream(ProjectConfig
                            .getProperty("KeyStoreAndTrustStore")),
                    ProjectConfig.getProperty(
                            "KeyStoreAndTrustStorePassword")
                            .toCharArray());
            KeyManagerFactory clientKeyManager = KeyManagerFactory
                    .getInstance("SunX509");
            clientKeyManager.init(
                    clientKeys,
                    ProjectConfig.getProperty(
                            "KeyStoreAndTrustStorePassword")
                            .toCharArray());
            // load server public key
            KeyStore serverPub = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            serverPub.load(
                    new FileInputStream(ProjectConfig
                            .getProperty("KeyStoreAndTrustStore")),
                    ProjectConfig.getProperty(
                            "KeyStoreAndTrustStorePassword")
                            .toCharArray());
            TrustManagerFactory trustManager = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance("SunX509");
            trustManager.init(serverPub);

            // use keys to create SSLSoket
            SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ssl.init(clientKeyManager.getKeyManagers(),
                    trustManager.getTrustManagers(),
                    SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"));

            sslClient = (SSLSocket) ssl.getSocketFactory().createSocket(
                    IP, Port);

            sslClient.setSoTimeout(TimeOut);
            System.out.println("connected to "
                    + sslClient.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            OutputStream outToServer = sslClient.getOutputStream();

            out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
            String contentToSend = ((String)Paylod);

            out.writeUTF(contentToSend);
            System.out.println(" sending data.... " + contentToSend);
            InputStream inFromServer = sslClient.getInputStream();
            in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            response = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Server says.... " + response);
            sslClient.close();
```